# Write a program that prints true if day of month is between March 20 and June 20, false otherwise using shell scripting

Tags: shell

```
#!/bin/bash -x

read -p " Enter Date:-" date
read -p " Enter Month:-" Month

if (( ($Month <= 6 & $date <= 20) ))
then
        echo $Month $date "True";

elif (( ($Month >= 3 & $Month < 6) & ($date<31)  ))
then
        echo $date $Month "True";

else

        echo "False";
fi
```

Comment: The "and" operator is `&&`

Comment: Is there any question here ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's one idea:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter Date: " date
read -p "Enter Month: " Month

# should validate input: non-blank, numeric

combo=0
res="false"
st=1

if [ $Month -ge 3 -a $Month -le 6 ]; then
    # 30 for Apr, Jun
    # 31 for Mar, May
    dlimit=$((30 + (Month % 2)))
    if [ $date -ge 1 -a $date -le $dlimit ]; then
        combo=$(((Month * 100) + date))
        # true Mar 20 to Jun 20
        if [ $combo -ge 320 -a $combo -le 620 ]; then
            res="true"
            st=0
        fi
    fi
fi

echo "$Month/$date $res"
exit $st
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, which works fine; don't use the condition in `elif`, otherwise it won't work!

```
#!/bin/bash -x
read -p " Enter Date:-" date
read -p " Enter Month:-" Month

if (( ($Month <= 6 && $date <= 20) && (($Month >= 3 && $date <= 20) && ($date<31)) ))
then
        echo $Month $date "True";
else

        echo "False";
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash -x

read -p " Enter Date:-" Date
read -p " Enter Month:-" Month

if [ $Month -gt 3 -a $Month -lt 6  -a  $Date -le 31 -a $Date -ge 1 ]
then
        echo $Date $Month "True"

elif [ $Month -eq 3 -a $Date -ge 20 -a $Date -le 31 ]
then
        echo $Date $Month "True"

elif [ $Month -eq 6 -a $Date -le 20 -a $Date -ge 1 ]
then
        echo $Date $Month "True"

else
        echo "False! Please Enter date between March 20 and June 20"
fi
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).